# xmlhttp.open GET invalid characters

Tags: mysql, xmlhttprequest

I thought that changing accents chars with

```
$GLOBALS['normalizeChars'] = array(
    'Á'=>'&Aacute;', 'É'=>'&Eacute;', 'Í'=>'&Iacute;', 'Ó'=>'&Oacute;', 'Ú'=>'&Uacute;', 'Ñ'=>'&Ntilde;',
    'á'=>'&aacute;', 'é'=>'&eacute;', 'í'=>'&iacute;', 'ó'=>'&oacute;', 'ú'=>'&uacute;', 'ñ'=>'&ntilde;'
);
```

and this function ...

```
function MakeIt($toClean){
    return strtr($toClean, $GLOBALS['normalizeChars']);
}
```

... will help me to replace *áéíóúñ* to a `&aacute;` etc...

But i'm still in trouble.

*mainfile.php* calls to a get_data.php that read mySQL content which uses `MakeIt();` to replace invalid chars. If I load get_data.php into a browser, chars are replaced correctly but when it's loaded from *mainfile.php* it returns invalid chars.

*mainfile.php*

```
<script>
    function ShowData(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("deal_rcpt").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("deal_rcpt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_data.php?event="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    ShowData(1) 
</script>
<div id="deal_rcpt"></div>
```

I think xmlhttp is not compatible with áéíóúñ chars.